# How to stop Eclipse from breaking at every caught exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

When I start debugging a java project, Eclipse keeps on breaking at random exceptions in 3rd party libraries, and it's so annoying.
any idea how to stop this?

I tried clicking on the (!) icon on the Breakpoints view, I can see that both "Suspend on caught exceptions" and "Suspend on uncaught exceptions" checkboxes are not checked.. still Eclipse breaks on the exception.

Although I'm not sure I'm using this window correctly, am I meant to select the exceptions one by one? Or is there a way to specify all exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exceptions you select with the "!" icon in the Breakpoint view are the exceptions you *want* to stop on. If you put "NullPointerException" in there and tell Eclipse to stop on "Caught and uncaught", your execution will stop on every last NullPointerException that gets thrown. Are you sure you haven't set a breakpoint on each of the "random exceptions" your execution stops on?

Comment: Question asker clearly states that this is not the problem.  Boxes are already unchecked.

Comment: Exactly, I have the same issue. I have no breakpoints enabled at all but Eclipse still stops on random exceptions in 3rd party code. See Steve Chambers' comment below, disabling 'suspend execution on uncaught exceptions' is probably the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue with Eclipse stopping on *uncaught* exceptions and resolved it by going to Window - Preferences - Java - Debug and unchecking "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions".

[Note: Not an answer to the exact question asked but highly related].

Comment: I suspect this is actually what the OP is asking about. I got caught by the same symptoms in the question, and your answer is the correct way to deal with this.