# Stop eclipse switch to Debug tab

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My problem is somewhat like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685199/how-can-i-stop-eclipses-servers-tab-from-grabbing-focus-when-start-stopping-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971212/how-to-stop-eclipse-breaking-at-every-caught-exception-when-running-in-debug), but none of those answer can apply to my situation.

I am running **tomcat** inside **Eclipse**, and **my project has some quartz job that run by schedule**. Those quartz job meets null pointer exception very often (since they must parse documents from an untrusted source) and surely the team who are working with those jobs can't fix them right away.

**The result is that Eclipse pop up debug tab every now and then, usually take up focus** so that I can't look what happen in console. Moreover, when Eclipse meet the exception, it pop out to take focus out of the program I currently work in (browser, email,...). It is very annoying.

Can I simply skip all the null pointer exceptions (since the fail of the jobs doesn't affect my program anyway) or is there a way to keep the focus on the console tab, and keep Eclipse doesn't complain everytime an exception pop out?

I'm very thankful for any possible solution.

**UPDATE:** I'm using Eclipse Helios with few plugins.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you looked in Eclipse's settings under Run/Debug? There are two useful options you can change;

- Activate the workbench when a breakpoint is hit
- Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit

Another obvious option would be to not use debug mode and "run" the application instead (AFAIK, breakpoints will never stop execution when "Running" code instead of "Debugging" it).

Comment: Is that you are telling about Debug Configuration? There I find a list of configuration for "Apache Tomcat", "eclipse application".. but the options are not there.

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have? You should be able to find these options via the menus at the top.... Window>Preferences, then look at the left side of the new window for "Run/Debug".

Comment: + 1 for not using debug, the OP has no breakpoints and doesn't want the program to stop, so what's the point.

Comment: You would be the cause of saving thousand of years of development time in the coming years. A saviour of mankind..blessed be thy soul.

Comment: Just want to add that if you have a workspace folder inside another workspace folder, (which you probably shouldn't, but that happened to be the case for me) Eclipse will always use the parent's workspace's setting.

Answer (score 2):

> Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Perspectives >
>
> > Open the associated perspective when an application suspsends:

Set to Never, or Prompt (as desired)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an unwanted Breakpoint set up in your Workspace. Open up your Breakpoints view, and you should see a breakpoint listed as a NullPointerException, RuntimeException or Exception. Uncheck it.

If you *want* to suspend the thread for all *other* occurences of NullPointerException, then you could look into Conditional Breakpoints (i.e. right-click on the breakpoint in the BreakPoints view, and click on Properties. You'll see a dialog with options for 'Conditional breakpoints'). That should set you on your way.

**Edit:** here's another possibility. Try looking in the Java Debug preferences:

> Menu > Window > Preferences

Then choose:

> Java > Debug

Now uncheck an option called:

> Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions