# A good way to debug nullPointerException

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception

I am using eclipse and programing in java. Sometimes I come across a nullPointerException that will plague me for hours. Is there anyway to debug nullPointerExceptions better and figure out what variable values are and other things that would cause null Pointer Exceptions.

Comment: look at the stack trace... it shows what line threw the NPE and you can put a break point there and see what variable is null...

Comment: The best way to learn how to debug NPE is to keep debugging them. You will get better at it with time. But the key is to find out where it's occurring and then check the variables. No magic here.

Comment: You could place `assert` statements into your code

Comment: Uh, look at the exception trace and see where the error is raised.  Put a stop there (or insert print statements) to figure out what value is null.  Trace that value back to its source.

Comment: Doesn't the exception tell you what line had the error?  Any given line of code shouldn't be doing a whole lot, and any given function should ideally only have a few lines of code (or otherwise be very simple even if it has many lines).  It shouldn't be hard to identify where the null value originated in any given function.

Comment: My problem is that with a function like function(a, b, c, d, e) it does not tell you which one of those variables is null.

Comment: @NoahHuppert: makes no sense. The stack trace will tell you the line of the NPE, and your debugger or logger or println will tell you which reference variable is null.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was asking if there was any debugger or logger that would help me.

Comment: @NoahHuppert: **any** debugger or logger will help you. Just give them a try. But again, there is no magic, you just have to trace the NPE to its source.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at the stack trace and read the line number where the `NullPointerException` is thrown. Almost always, the line has some method invocation like

```
x.getValue()
```

If `x` is `null`, you get a `NullPointerException`. If the method at the top of the stack trace is not your code, trace the stack all the way back until you do reach your code. Very often in this case, you are passing `null` to a method that doesn't like `null` parameters. Find it and fix it.

Also, very often when you encounter a method that is not yours that is throwing a `NullPointerException`, read the documentation. For example, look at [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

> **Throws**:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if `target` or `replacement` is `null`.

It doesn't get much clearer than that!

Here's an example:

[image]

Looking at line 4, we see `foo.bar()`. This implies that `foo` is `null`. That one is easy. Let's look at another example:

[image]

Tracing back to your code, we see that `s.replace(target, replacement)` is throwing. We should inspect `target` and `replacement`. Let's attach a debugger:

[image]

Aha! `replacement` is `null`. You can do the same thing in Eclipse. Set a breakpoint for when an exception is thrown, and use it to inspect the parameters to your method. I'm primitive here because I come from a school of thought where I genuinely believe everyone would be better off if they learned to do it the hard way first. Leaky abstractions and all that.

Comment: An example or a screenshot with freehanded circles would be nice :)

Comment: My problem is that with a function like function(a, b, c, d, e) it does not tell you which one of those variables is null.

Comment: @hexafraction: or even better, 8x10 in glossy pictures with circles and arrows and a paragraph on the back of each one explaining what each one was to be used.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I had some of those but Jason walked in with a seeing eye dog.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - You forgot the dog smelling prints.

Answer (score 19):

1. While debugging can you use the `BreakPoints` view, to capture the null
   pointers.

   > Window -> Show View -> Breakpoints

   In the view there is a `"J!"` that lets you set breakpoints on
   exceptions. You can set `java.lang.NullPointerException`. So once
   null pointer exception is thrown, you can check which variable is causing
   null.
2. Other thing you can do is capture possible null pointer access while you are coding. Off-course you cant capture all the Null Pointers using this setting. But still its helpful, set the following settings in your eclipse.

   > Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/warnings -> Null analysis

Comment: It may also be a debug setting in eclipse that is halting program execution on uncaught exceptions. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32606736/2544255

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to make `NullPointerException` less of an issue:

1. Use the [@Nullable annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076296/nullable-annotation-usage).
2. Test the values of arguments for `null` in constructors and setters (avoid setters in plain old Java code). If you do this a lot you could make an (Eclipse) source code template to quickly generate the code. This is called "failfast" - you don't wait for the exception to be thrown when the value is being used further in the code, e.g. after storing it in a field.
3. Make sure that you perform a minimum amount (e.g. 1 or 2) of operations per line. If you don't you will have to find out where in the single line expression the `NullPointerException` occurred.
4. Don't use `null` in fields to indicate state. Instead, use e.g. an `enum State`. E.g. don't do `if (socket == null) { // not connected }` as it easy to forget to check for `null` later on. A explicit state is not so easy to forget.
5. Don't initialize local variables to `null` unless explicitly needed. Actually, if you handle your scope and exceptions correctly you should be able to mark most variables `final`. Replacing the default `printStacktrace()` methods with `throw new IllegalStateException("Unhandled program state", e)` helps because it is seen as an exit point of a code block.

After a lot of programming you will find the number of `NullPointerException`s go down.