# Android - Sugar lib NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am using the Sugar lib for android and checked the example on their site: [hier](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

```
UserData udata;
udata = new UserData(fname.getText()
                            .toString(), lname.getText()
                            .toString(), email.getText()
                            .toString(), country.getText()
                            .toString(), aboutu.getText()
                            .toString(), pass.getText()
                            .toString());
                    udata.save();  //here is the NullPointerException
                    UserData ud = UserData.findById(UserData.class, 1);
```

Exception:

```
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:47)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at com.arssoft.exp.dialog.RegisterDialog$2.onClick(RegisterDialog.java:114)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
09-02 16:42:55.399: E/AndroidRuntime(25162): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The androidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arssoft.chechenkitchen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.arssoft.exp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.arssoft.exp.RecipeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="sugar_recipeuser.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.arssoft.exp" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

The .jar of sugar lib is downloaded and in the libs folder.
I have no idea why it throws this exception.
I just followed the Sample of this site: [hier](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871825/a-good-way-to-debug-nullpointerexception) if you are on eclipse

Comment: Did you ever work out the issue, I am currently having a similar problem.

Comment: No. Instead I used SharedPreferences to save data on device.

Answer (score 8):

try add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml
`android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"`

example:

`<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">`

Comment: I guess because Sugar Orm implements a custom Application class that must be instantiated at startup

Comment: BTW if you're using a custom Application class you should make it extend  SugarApp instead of Application