# Drawing Rectangle From Another Class

Tags: java, graphics2d, java-2d

I'm working on creating a simple Java2D program. It is supposed to draw rectangles from another class but it does not work. I'd really appreciate it if one of you guys could take a few moments to look where I'm going wrong. This is my last assignment due tomorrow.

Here's the code which I have worked on so far:

Block.java

```
public class Block extends JPanel {

    public Graphics2D g;
    protected int posX = 0;
    protected int posY = 0;
    protected int w = 100;
    protected int h = 100;

    public void draw() {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(posX, posY, w, h);
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class main {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Block[] pie = new Block[5];
    Timer timer;

    main() {
        final JPanel screen = new JPanel() {

            int x = 0;
            int step = 10;

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponent(g);

                pie[0].g = (Graphics2D) g;
                pie[0].draw();

            }

        };

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Lab");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(screen);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new main();
            }
        });     
    }

}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: So what's the problem? What is supposed to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: I have no idea. There are several messages appear on the console :
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at main$1.paintComponent(main.java:54)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)

where line 54 refers to <code> pie[0].g = (Graphics2D) g; </code>

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17871842/635678 for help.  what is line 54 in main.java ?

Comment: @DanO : I've just edit my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Block[] pie = new Block[5];
```

You create an array of size 5, but you have not added any Block's to the Array,

```
pie[0].g = (Graphics2D) g;
pie[0].draw();
```

So when you try to reference the object at index 0, you get a NPE.

So at the start of your constuctor you might add:

```
pie[0] = new Block();
```

Also, your draw method should be defined something like:

```
public void draw(Graphics g)
```

then in your painting code you would use:

```
pie[0].draw(g);
```

That is you don't need to store a Graphics object in your Block class. Pass the Graphics object to the method.